# Datagrid view not displaying correctly

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Any ideas what would be causing this?[image]

I have a datagridview with results in already which I clear then load other results into. This is what is happening. Its in VB.

heres my code:

```
 Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        ds.Clear()
        ds.Tables.Clear()
        resultsTable.DataSource = ds

        Dim str As String = "Data Source=" & My.Settings.dbServer & ";uid=" & My.Settings.dbUsername & ";pwd=" & My.Settings.dbPassword & ";database=" & My.Settings.dbDatabase
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
        Dim com As String = "SELECT * 

             FROM Scripts
               where completed = 2
             group by   PrescriptionID"
        Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)

        Adpt.Fill(ds, "Emp")

        resultsTable.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


    End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using
    resultsTable.Rows.Clear()
after the third line

Comment: Thanks, but getting:  Cannot find table 0. exception

Comment: maybe try just using ds instead of ds.tables(0)